# When trying to access files throug sftp request takes too long and hangs the server

Tags: django, python-django-storages

I am using a server to store my files, and I have employed storages.backends.sftpstorage.SFTPStorage to manage URLs, downloads, and uploads. However, I occasionally encounter the following issue when I try to get files from server, causing the entire server to hang and become temporarily unavailable.
My [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmr1H.png).
My sftp configuration

```
SFTP_STORAGE_HOST = "host"
SFTP_STORAGE_ROOT = "/Files"
SFTP_STORAGE_UID = 1000
SFTP_STORAGE_PARAMS = {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "port": 5522,
    "timeout": 4,
    "banner_timeout": 1,
    "auth_timeout": 1,
    "channel_timeout": 4,
}
```

My view to access files:

```
    def get(self, request, name=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """Only for SFTP users."""
        SFS = SFTPStorage()
        if SFS.exists(name):
            file = SFS._read(name)
            type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(name)
            response = HttpResponse(file, content_type=type)
            response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="{filename}'.format(filename=name)
            return response
        raise Http404
```

I tried to set timeouts, but they didn't help much.